# Parsing irregular HTML table

Tags: java, html, parsing

I have a html table I need to parse.http://codepen.io/harindu95/full/apVVNV/

```
<html>
...... I can't post the code because it apparently exceed the limit
```

Even though it looks visually alright it has uneven rows.(some rows couple together.) Because of that I can't get the correct column number for a cell.

Do you guys have any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the DOM, i can see you have some rows with rowspan=2, which would cause uneven rows (by design).  Of course, you didn't provide any code, and the link you provided failed to load any resources, css, and javascript, so we're essentially looking at 2 different webpages

Comment: As I am scrapping the page I only downloaded the raw html. SO yeah We are looking at the same page :). Anyway thanks for the insight.